# Probability of drawing three different suits with a joker included in a single deck.

Tags: probability, card-games

I [found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000750/probability-of-picking-3-playing-cards-that-belong-to-different-suits) how to calculate the probability of drawing three cards from a standard 52 card deck and have all three be different suits.
It's $39/51⋅26/50=169/425$ which is 0.397647...
If a joker was added to the deck would I simple add one to the denominators in the above equation or do I subtract the probability of drawing the joker from the result above?

I plan on working on similar problems so is there a good book/PDF/link one may provide that deals with these types of card combination probabilities?

Comment: It's "suits" not "suites".

Comment: To your question, the joker becomes a new suit, though one with fewer cards than the others.  The same sort of counting mechanism works, though it is probably easier to split it into two parts (those good hands which contain the joker and those that don't).

Comment: @lulu you have 61k rep. You can just edit his question instead of commenting on a typo.

Comment: @Newb: that would correct the post, but might not educate the poster. I support lulu's commenting strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 13 cards of each suit in a 52-card deck.

If you add a joker, then there are still 13 cards of each suit in a deck, but the deck is now 53 cards.

Therefore the probability of drawing three differently suited cards is:

$$1 \cdot 39/52 \cdot 26/51 \approx 37.5\%$$

So your intuition that you just add one to the denominator is correct.

Comment: Your $53$ should be $52$. I didn't just edit your answer, because that might not have educated you :-)

Comment: @TonyK thanks for catching